# Phaser - Check if game was paused

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am currently creating a game using [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) and SignalR (Websockets).

It seems like Phaser will pause if I open another tab, and it will fail to process the commands I send from SignalR. Is there anyway to check if the game was paused, So I can request an update state from the server?

I'm using:

```
game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;
```

which works when I change programs, but not tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Phaser's `State` does have both a [`paused`](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.State.html#paused) and `pauseUpdate` method.

Do note that according to [the documentation](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Stage.html#disableVisibilityChange), the browser can still choose to pause your game even if `game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;` is set (which seems to be what you're running into), and the pause events won't trigger. I'd assume your browser is doing this for performance reasons.

So it appears that you should choose to either use `paused` *or* set `game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;`